# How can I plot coordinates of x and y axes that are very close on html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to plot some points on canvas through x and y coordinates. [First codepen](https://codepen.io/mahidaparth7-the-typescripter/pen/XxbgRJ) I have created does not plot all points, I think it has scale issue. But can not figure out how to set proper scale.
Here in my [second codepen](https://codepen.io/mahidaparth7-the-typescripter/pen/vVOZJe) all points are plotted very closely. The points plotted creates a text **hello zap**

Here in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahidaparth7/m2zbxdy4/) I have plotted all points through scatter chart. Please refer codepen and fiddle for all data.Can anyone please suggest me a proper way to plot this points properly.
Thank You.

```
 //html code
     <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

    //js code
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        width = canvas.width = 800,
        height = canvas.height = 400;

// var stats = [40, 65, 72, 120, 250, 87, 100, 42];
var stats =   [
   {
        "x": 54.75,
        "y": 71,
        "dotType": 17,
        "pressure": 19,
        "timestamp": 1535708931610
      },
      {
        "x": 54.7599983215332,
        "y": 71,
        "dotType": 18,
        "pressure": 27,
        "timestamp": 1535708931619
      }
]
context.translate(0, height);
context.scale(1, -1);

context.fillStyle = '#f6f6f6';
context.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

var left = 0,
        prev_stat = stats[0].y,
        move_left_by = 100;

for(stat in stats) {
    the_stat = stats[stat].y;
  console.log(left, prev_stat);
    console.log(left+move_left_by, the_stat)
    context.beginPath();

    context.arc(left+move_left_by, the_stat,1, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    context.stroke();

    prev_stat = the_stat;
    left += move_left_by
}
```

Edit:

This data is from a [neoPen](https://www.neosmartpen.com/en/?noredirect=en_US), whenever I write something on a paper with that pen on A4 size paper it send me coordinates of that page.This points are near because just a text written on a page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking at your [second codepen](https://codepen.io/mahidaparth7-the-typescripter/pen/vVOZJe?editors=0011).

First you have the data string that you are breaking into points and you put those points in the `canvasPts` array.

Next you are redeclaring the points of the `canvasPts`, deleting all the pervious points.

Furthermore:  the points of the `canvasPts` are all almost in the same spot. Please take a look at the values for the x and y.

And this is not all. You are dividing the values for x and y coordinates by 100, making them even nearer.

You do not declare a size for your canvas, making your canvas of 300/150 px.

Supposing I would try to draw the SVG path for your data, this appears to be a group of lines with a length of 0. There is nothing to draw.

Please edit your question explaining how did you get your data.

**UPDATE**:

In order to avoid cluttering I've put your data in an external file.
I'm doing it 2 ways:

**first in svg**: SVG is easily scalable, and was easier for me tu understand what happens. The vewBox for the svg is `viewBox="53.5 68 12 5"` which means that the svg canvas begins at x=53.5, y=68. The width of the svg canvas is 68 and the height is 5.

**In Canvas-HTML5**: I'm scaling the context 10 times since otherwise it would be extrmely small: `ctx.scale(10,10);` In order to achieve the same result in canvas and since I'm translating the context ctx.translate(-53.5, -68.0);

```js
//SVG
let d=`M${data[0].x},${data[0].y}L`
for(let i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
  d += `${data[i].x},${data[i].y} `
}

test.setAttributeNS(null, "d", d);




//canvas//////

const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 120;
let ch = canvas.height = 50;

ctx.lineWidth = .1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "black";

ctx.scale(10,10);
ctx.translate(-53.5, -68.0);


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(data[0].x,data[0].y);
for(let i = 1; i < data.length; i++){
  ctx.lineTo(data[i].x,data[i].y);
}

ctx.stroke();
```

```css
svg,canvas{border:1px solid}

path{fill: none; stroke:black; stroke-width:.05}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="53.5 68 12 5">
  <path id="test" />
</svg>

<canvas></canvas>
  
  <script src='https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/dd442277a45b6cf1b5cc690200cdb3cf.js'></script>
```

Comment: I have added the source from where I am getting data in edit

Comment: if points are too near , my question is how on line chart it appearing properly? chart library is also based on canvas. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ParthMahida. The coords are all wrong. Please show me an image of what you want to do or something very similar.

Comment: @ParthMahida. I have no idea how the smart pen is vorking. but Take a look at your coords: The first point: "x": 54.75,"y": 71 and the second point "x": 54.7599983215332,"y": 71. The y is the same. the x is very very near. at a distance of 0.009. This when the radius for each point is 6.

Comment: I just wants to plot all points like scatter chart, yeah they are near but if we increase they might be visible. Please take a look at jsfiddle mentioned in question.

Comment: @ParthMahida: I've updated my answer. Please take a look